# Can't get "Find Beds" filter to work

Tags: mcedit

I lost my home bed, which I had slept in, after dying. I tried "Find Beds" filter, but it's not outputting anything on console window and freezes my mac. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of Minecraft are you using and what version of MCedit?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, but I finally figured it out!

Not sure if this is the case with all filters or not (I'm very new to Minecraft and brand new to MCEdit), but at least in the case of the "find bed" filter, the next is not outputted in MCEdit, but rather in a Command Prompt window.

For me, it blended in because I already had a couple command prompts open... but anyway, check your taskbar and it will be there!